# Is a question about the effects of climate on political loyalty on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked this question about the effect of climate on Union-Confederacy loyalties in the Civil War on the history site? https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8309/what-are-exceptions-to-the-hypothesis-that-climate-determined-regional-loyalty

Would such a question be on topic here? If yes, would it make sense to cross link it?

Comment: Climate = affects crops = south grew cotton = south wanted slavery for the cotton fields. So, almost seems like a climatology/science question more than anything.

Comment: @DA: Your "answer" is better than anything I've seen so far on the history site. Care to answer the question?

Comment: @DA. If you decide to answer on History.SE, you might be interested in examining the role the invention of the cotton gin played (caused massive growth in cotton production that was - due to climate - mostly concentrated in the South).

Comment: @TomAu let me think about it. There's only so many SE sites a person has time for in a day. ;)

Comment: @DA: Fair enough.

Comment: @YannisRizos - That.

Answer (score 2):

Political history is on topic on Politics, according to the [relevant Meta discussion](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/is-political-history-within-the-scope-of-the-site).

However I think the question in question is more suitable for History than our site, and since it was already asked and answered I don't see any reason to post it here as well. Cross posting is generally discouraged, it is extremely rare that a question equally fits two sites, and when that happens it's always preferable to try and tailor the questions to the respective site audiences. If you do go ahead and cross post, please don't just copy paste the question.