# Is there any difference in [history] and [political-history]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

While [political history is on-topic](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/is-political-history-within-the-scope-of-the-site) we have two tags

- [history](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) - 108 questions

  > Questions on the history of politics, political action and political debate, as well as historical political figures, heads of state etc. Also including any historical political actions and situations which may be of relevance to modern day scenarios.
- [political-history](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-history) - 27 questions, no excerpt

I would suggest we synonym these to [political-history](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-history) (since general history has its own site) and move the excerpt over

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the proposed solution, but the PH tag is indeed a mystery.

Comment: Yea I don't think we need the political adjective in there as well, it is implied by being on this site and confirmed by the excerpt. Leaving out the adjective works for other tags as well, e.g. [parties].

Answer (score 2):

I've added a proposed tag synonym in the opposite direction, i.e. to https://politics.stackexchange.com/tags/history/synonyms since JJ's comment has received some upvotes. The synonym still needs some upvotes of its own to become effective.

Comment: That works for me. I upvoted it. While we're at it, might as well note [there's other synonyms to vote on](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested)