# Are questions about ancient politics allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

The vast, vast majority of questions here are about contemporary politics, but the [help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) doesn't seem to include era as a criteria for topicality.

Are questions on ancient politics allowed on this site as long as they meet the other rules of topicality, clarity, etc.? For example, if I have a clear, specific, answerable, and non-antagonistic question about speaking protocol in the Roman Senate in the final years of the Republic, is that on-topic here because it is a question about politics or is it off-topic for failing to be about *contemporary* politics?

Comment: See related questions, [Cutoff between Politics and History](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5836/26455) and [Is political history within the scope of the site?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32/26455).

Comment: The [top voted answer on this from Philipp](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5839/19301) says "For me, the criteria about whether a question belongs on Politics or on History is whether or not the answer is still relevant for the politics of today." So, based on that, the answer would be no. That makes sense to me, since you'll get a much better answer to your question from a historian than a political scientist or expert on politics. If you disagree with that or think that doesn't apply here, maybe explain that in the question?