# How far back in history do political history questions "on topic" for this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

Seeing that political history is "on topic" based on [this answer](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34/28047), **how far back in history** is "on topic" before making the question more suitable for History.SE?

For example:

1. A question about politics in **Ancient Rome** (example: political dynamics between Emperor Nero and upper class Romans) or **Ancient Greece** (example: power dynamics between Athens and the rest of the Delian League) or **Ancient China** (example: how Qin Shi Huang could unify China and became the first emperor)?
2. A question from the **Biblical period** (example: rivalry between the Northern and Southern Israel)
3. A question from EVEN FURTHER back: **Sumerian civilization** (example: the power extent of a city's king in relation to the priests) or **Ancient Egypt** (example: 2 great powers dynamics between Egypt and the Hittites)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put all of those examples as off topic for this site and I would say even as early as 100-200 years ago is more suited for history then politics.

Comment: Really?  Then the politics of the 1648 [Peace of Westphalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_of_Westphalia) from where our **current** foundation of international relations originated would also be off topic?  As does the politics of the 13 colonies around the time of the founding the United States?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Really as that is now a historical event.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying.